# Редактирыемые поля карточки клиентов и работа с API

Tags: php, mysql, api

Пишу CRM сейчас сделал возможно задавать свои поля для карточки клиентов, но не могу понять как мне через API принимать например новые созданные поля.

input_check - здесь задается вид поля id поля, название поля (отображается в карточке клиента).

input_content - в этой таблице идет привязка к id_input_check (виду поля) и к карточке клиента id_client, и конечно content.

В API у меня данные приходят при помощи JSON

Загвоздка вот в чем, как мне записать приходящие данные в нужное поле input_content, если например мой клиент передает нестандартное поле, которое через JSON задается как переменная input_212, где цифра это как раз id в таблице input_content

**Как мне прочитать название переменной, найти в ней id и потом из этой переменной вытащить ее значение (content)?**

Покажите решение... может кто делал

Comment: Покажите код, может вы что то делали. Вы думаете у всех поля, значения и задачи одни и те же?

Comment: Да у меня API самым обычным образом  ловит переменные $_POST['phone'] например, потом заносит в базу. А вот если например поле созданное пользователем и в него надо занести данные через API т.е. поле название которого я не могу предугадать...